# Wrong sequence of plots and texts in a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

When I run the following for loop in a jupyter notebook

```
for index,image in enumerate(pics):
   plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
   plt.imshow(image.squeeze())
   print("Some text ")
```

I get the output

```
Some text 
Some text 
Some text 

<1st pic>
<2nd pic>
<3rd pic>
```

where  <1st pic> , etc. are just placeholders in lieu of the real pictures, which are not depicted here.

Obviously, The intended output would be

```
<1st pic>
Some text 

<2nd pic>
Some text 

<3rd pic>
Some text
```

How can I get the intended output when I want to treat the text independently and not e.g. as image caption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not telling him to tell matplotlib to show you the figure. I suppose you used `%matplotlib inline` in the notebook, that causes a `plt.show()` to be run at the end of the cell.

```
for index in range(3):
    plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
    plt.show()
    print("Some text ")
```

Out:

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7ff844b2b048>
Some text 
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7ff86cc4a7b8>
Some text 
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7ff86908dcf8>
Some text
```